# Detecting a Process is already running in windows using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

How do I detect if a process is already running under the Windows Task Manager?  I'd like to get the memory and cpu usage as well.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/51148/562769

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked into the [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) Class.

Answer (score 28):

Simple example...

```
bool processIsRunning(string process)
{
    return (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(process).Length != 0);
}
```

Oops... forgot the mem usage, etc...

```
bool processIsRunning(string process)
{
System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(process);
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process proc in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current physical memory : " + proc.WorkingSet64.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Total processor time : " + proc.TotalProcessorTime.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Virtual memory size : " + proc.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString());
}
return (processes.Length != 0);
}
```

(I'll leave the mechanics of getting the data out of the method to you - it's 17:15 here, and I'm ready to go home.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) Class.
There is a [GetProcesses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses) and a [GetProcessesByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname) method that will get a list of all the existing processes in an array.

The `Process` object has all the information you need to detect if a process is running.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to find out about the IE Processes that are running:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("IEXPLORE");

if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
{
   foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
   {                        
      String virtualMem = p.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString();
      String physicalMem = p.WorkingSet64.ToString();
      String cpu = p.TotalProcessorTime.ToString();                      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use WMI to query something along the lines of

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '<your process name here>'"
```

Especially processor usage is a bit tricky with WMI, though. You are probably better off with System.Diagnostics.Process, as [Ian Jacobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187915/detecting-a-process-is-already-running-in-windows-using-c-net#187927) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach ( WindowsProcess in Process.GetProcesses) 
{ 
    if (WindowsProcess.ProcessName == nameOfProcess) { 
        Console.WriteLine(WindowsProcess.WorkingSet64.ToString); 
        Console.WriteLine(WindowsProcess.UserProcessorTime.ToString); 
        Console.WriteLine(WindowsProcess.TotalProcessorTime.ToString); 
    } 
}
```