# how to open explorer only one time by C# code

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this code for open explorer (by pressing button):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe",@"C:\Help.html");
```

the problem is, if i press the button more than one time - the explorer will open a lot of shows

how to force the explorer to open only one time ?

thanks

Comment: have a look at this answer, may point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187915/detecting-a-process-is-already-running-in-windows-using-c-sharp-net

Comment: you can disable the button once you have clicked once ..

Comment: @MMK I was thinking that as well, but what happens if the user closes the browser and wants to re-launch from the OP's app?

Comment: Why don't you disable the button just after you click on it ?

Comment: Google it and you can find this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/745389ab-5745-477b-b698-8097e3fb33b2/

Comment: @Jay comment will lead to right direction than

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore").Length == 0)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe", @"C:\Help.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable button.
2. Control clicking by a flag

ie ; 
    on_btn_clkd()
     {
       if(!previouslyClickd)
        {
         (Click functionalities)
         previouslyClicked = false;
        }
          else
        return ;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this piece of code:

```
bool ProcessIsRunning(string process)
{
    return (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(process).Length != 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
if (!ProcessIsRunning("IExplore.exe"))
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe",@"C:\Help.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IeProcess = new Process();
        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    }

private void buttonStackoverflow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startInfo.FileName = "www.Stackoverflow.com";
        IeProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
        IeProcess.Start();
    }

    private void buttongoogle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startInfo.FileName = "www.google.com";
        IeProcess.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `ShDocVw.dll`..
declare in instance of Internet explorer in your class

```
InternetExplorer wBrowser;
```

and in your button click add

```
if (wBrowser==null)
    {
     wBrowser = new InternetExplorer();
     wBrowser.Visible = true;
     wBrowser.Navigate(@"C:\Help.html");
    }
```

you need to add reference to `ShDocVw` which you will find in `System32` in your project and import namespace `using SHDocVw;`

Answer (score 0):

If sour default browser is `IE` just try this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Help.html");
```